# What is the name of these blue seeds?

Tags: identification, flowers, seeds

What is the name of the blue seeds in the upper left part of this picture?

[image]

Comment: I am afraid all the blue colored dried flowers/plant parts are dyed! If you could point out the one with the texture you like, we could tell you the plant. Are you interested in dried flowers or the color? -